# Get parameter name from XML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, jasper-reports

I am trying to pull the parameters from a Jasper Reports XML file (which I upload).

This is what I have so far:

```
 var file = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
            //You could insert a check here to ensure proper file type
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file);
            reader.onloadend = function(){

                var parser = new DOMParser();

                var doc = parser.parseFromString( reader.result, "application/xml");

                //doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter")[0]

                var parameters = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
```

Then, I can do `parameters[0]` and get:

```
<parameter name=​"report_type_id" class=​"java.lang.Integer">​</parameter>​
```

What I want is the parameter's name.

This is what the XML looks like (truncated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-25T10:35:12 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1fe7af1a-adc5-48b5-a571-37c521a3ccea">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="dev_selection"/>
    <parameter name="report_type_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from reports where report_type_id = $P{report_type_id}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="sql" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="report_type_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
```

Mick

Comment: Would `parameters[0].getAttribute('name')` work?

Comment: Yes, it most certainly would! Thanks.

Comment: What's the easiest way to get all the parameter names? (Only one in the example but more than in the real world.) forEach through parameters or something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var file = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file);
reader.onloadend = function () {

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, "application/xml");
  var params = doc.querySelectorAll('parameter');
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    names.push(params[i].getAttribute('name'));
  }

}
```